# Add typescript to only one component in a existing vue project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

So I have a Vue project its quite big. Every time I tried to add typescript, it caused bunch of errors so I don't want to spend weeks fixing them. so I decided to go back. I would like to add typescript in it without having to change much or just adding a typescript in one of the custom components so that I can work with variables better. Can anyone direct me how to add typescript to only one component in the project without changing main.js? and effecting any imports. I can't find anything online that can cover this.

Comment: `<script lang="ts">` ?

Comment: lang="ts" doesn't work. I already tried that and it gives me this weird error.                                              Module parse failed: Unexpected token (88:27)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| ], -1 /* HOISTED */)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, we can achieve your goal.
The TypeScript compiler *supports a mix of JavaScript and TypeScript files* if we use the compiler *option* *--allowJs* :

1. TypeScript files are compiled.
2. JavaScript files are simply copied  over to the *output directory* (after a few simple type checks).

This is what tsconfig.json should look like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ···
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

**Note :** I have assumed you have properly configured TS with srcDir and outDir.